# Is it acceptable to split a question into two different questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

[I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56506057/3151675) about SwiftUI with the original title of the following:

> How can I access other views/view properties declared in the same view in SwiftUI?

[Here's the original question before the edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56506057/1)

After I got [an amazing answer from user J. Doe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56506163/3151675) ([here's the original state of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56506163/2)), I realized that this title is confusing and my original question is really two questions in one (accessing modifiers of a view and declaring a view as a variable in the `body` of a view).

So, I edited the question to be only about declaring a view as a variable and [asked a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56506318/3151675) which is only about accessing the modifiers of a view. I included the link of the new question [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56506057/3151675#comment99600105_56506163) under the (now accepted) answer and [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56506057/3151675#comment99600029_56506163) that they should remove the first half of the answer and include it in an answer under the new question.

I could've written a community wiki answer under the second question, but I didn't want to "steal" upvotes from J. Doe, so I chose the option above.

I upvoted and accepted both answers by J. Doe.

Did I do anything wrong here? If so, what should I do differently in a similar situation?

<sup>Also, to be honest, I'm kind of afraid of the Meta effect. If I did something horrible here, feel free to vote my questions down, but I really don't want any of my answerers to be affected by this.</sup>

Comment: Not that many contributors enjoy a question edit that invalidates their answer.  But it looks like Doe was quite willing to accommodate that, perhaps because he thought it was a good idea as well, so not a problem.

Comment: The obvious case where harm is done, is if the existing answers no longer make sense with the new question. It's a balance between getting things right, and preserving history. After the question edit (and say, 5 years), I might not even find the question by searching, let alone be able to make sense of its answers I might need.

Comment: If the answers turn out to answer the wrong question because the OP's wording is confusing, then by all means edit it to turn it into the actual question, otherwise you'll never get the answer you need.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**tl;dr**: What you did was not just acceptable but even a good thing, if not *the* right thing to do.

In general, editing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers is heavily frowned-upon for several reasons:

- It wastes the answerer's time: they took the time to compose an answer to a question that was then un-asked.
- If they don't notice that the question has changed (and there is no automatic notification AFAIK), it may make them look bad.
- Since the answer doesn't answer the question, it will be down-voted.

The most important reason why people react heavily to changing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers is that such edits are often a sign of a [*Chameleon Question*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/2988), which are often huge time-sinks, and often turn out to become ever more specialized with each iteration, until they reach the point where they are not useful to anyone except the asker (and sometimes not even that).

**HOWEVER**: None of that applies to your case!

- You didn't waste anybody's time. Not really. All the answerer needs to do is cut & paste half of his answer to the second question.
- By leaving a comment, you both notified the answerer that the question has changed, as well as any readers that this answer applies to an earlier version of the question.
- Likewise, by leaving a comment, you notified any voters that the answer applies to an earlier version of the question.

In fact, you didn't really invalidate any answers *at all*, the answers are just answering more than what you are asking.

And your question is clearly not a Chameleon Question that constantly changes what is being asked. First off, you only made one change, secondly, you are not asking something different, you are only asking less, and third, actually you are not even doing that; you are just splitting it.

Most importantly, you explicitly engaged in communication with the answerer in the comments and the wider community.

So, in summary, what you did improved your question, improved the site, made the web a better place, and didn't hurt anyone. All good.

Comment: I don't know. I was getting my torch lit and my pitchfork ready; but then I finished reading the question and everything seemed all too reasonable. As part of a potentially enraged mob, I was hurt by the disappointment these measured actions and tone brought. Will _somebody_ think of the mobs?

Comment: @yivi [Just for you...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLvGnro4Cgw) :-)

Comment: I'd add that editing the question itself to notify about the split would be even better than just a single comment (comments might be deleted at any time etc.)

Comment: @walen Editing the question will not notify the answerer that the question has changed; a comment (to the answer) will.