# Do the rules for writing a question for a Q&A post differ from the rules which are followed when writing a question you are not planning to answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

It is often emphasized ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/434069), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385914/8565438), and often in chat, comments), that a post should contain **only one** question.

However, I often encounter a post with multiple questions and answers to all of them by the same user, which I find very helpful ([example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe) and [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781634/aggregation-in-pandas)). They are all from high-rep users.

If I see such an unanswered question, I flag it for not being focused.

Is it the case that **if you answer your own question, then the criteria by which I should judge the question is different or there are other (unwritten) rules for high rep users**?

---

*(Since I find their posts useful, I wouldn't mind if they wouldn't follow the same rules - I am asking mostly to determine if I can write a "bad" question if I also answer it.)*

Comment: The criteria would not be any different for questions the author intends to self-answer or for questions by high-rep users.

Comment: The same rules apply, it's just sometimes popularity takes precedence.

Comment: It's a self answer. Canonical questions are typically exempt from this rule, since they are meant for people to browse and find.

Comment: I don't think the posts this question got associated with actually answers this question, as they don't deal with the acceptability of posting many questions once in a Q&A post, which this post explicitly talks about.

Comment: They are useful anyway, thanks @gnat.